# Redux mapStateToProps on a array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I have class Todo with redux mapStateToProps(state) function.
The problem is this class has multiple Todos objects, One for each Todo.
 How can I distinguish between the different todos? How can I find out the unique index of each object?

A state for example

`rows: [
    {
      title: 'Todo 1',
      isDone: true,
    },
    {
      title: 'Todo 2',
      isDone: false,
    },
    {
      title: 'Todo 3',
      isDone: true,
    },
  ],`

Comment: Any code sample? BTW you can always use a `Map` object with route path as key and Todo object as value.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the shape of your Redux state.  Can you post an example?  Even if it is just pseudocode.

Comment: Is there any chance you can add an ID to these TODOS when you create them?

Comment: Unless you need to keep duplicate Todos, you'll probably be better off using an object in the state, instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a package like nanoid (https://github.com/ai/nanoid) to create a very random ID and assign each task an ID. Nanoid has a very low collision rate so it'll be better than using Math.random or any such methods. You shouldn't depend on the title as a unique identifier unless you're going to enforce a 'no duplicate title rule'.

With the unique ID reference you'll be able to filter through them easily.

```
const someId = 'asdf';
const rows = [
    {
        id: 'asdf'
    } 
]
const yourTask = rows.filter(row => row.id === someId);
```

maioman's suggestion of using an object instead of an Array does work too.

```
const rows = {
    'Some Task Name': {
        ...
    },
    someTaskId: {
        name: 'Some Task Name'
    }
};

const yourTask = rows['Some Task Name'];
const otherTask = rows.someTaskId;
```